# Plot isolated points using D3 line on canvas

Tags: javascript, d3.js, firefox, html5-canvas, visualization

I was playing around with D3 line generator using canvas and I noticed that Chrome behaves differently than other browsers when displaying isolated data points, if `lineCap` is set to `round` or `square`.

In the screenshots below, I'm plotting three times the following data set.

```js
const datapoints = [0, 1, null, 3, null, 5, 6, 7, 8];
```

The data point `3` is isolated because it is preceded and followed by `null`'s and the line generator sets

```js
line().defined(d => d !== null)
```

so there will be a gap between the points `1-3` and `3-5`.

All the three lines use the same line generator. The difference between the three is that the red line has `lineCap = 'butt'`, the blue line has `lineCap = 'round'` and the green line has `lineCap = butt`, but it adds circles where the data point is not `null`.

As you can see from the screenshots, in Chrome the blue line renders the isolated data point, while it does not on Firefox (and Safari).

I admit that Chrome's behaviour comes in handy, because I get isolated data points on screen without the need of manually placing them. Do you know if is there a way to achieve the same result on Firefox (and Safari)?

You can find the code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-wildflower-8145y1).

#### Screenshots

[image: Chrome]
[image: Firefox]

#### Code

Here's the meaningful portion of the code that handles the plotting, however you can find the code [in this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-wildflower-8145y1).

```js
const brush = line()
  .defined((d) => d !== null)
  .x((d) => scale(d))
  .curve(curveLinear)
  .context(ctx);

function drawLine(
  data,
  y,
  { color = "black", lineCap = "butt", points = false }
) {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.strokeStyle = color;
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.lineCap = lineCap;
  ctx.beginPath();
  brush.y(y)(data);

  if (points) {
    data.forEach((point) => {
      ctx.moveTo(scale(point), y);
      ctx.arc(scale(point), y, 1, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    });
  }

  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();
}

const datapoints = [0, 1, null, 3, null, 5, 6, 7, 8];

drawLine(datapoints, 120, { color: "darkred" });
drawLine(datapoints, 140, { color: "darkblue", lineCap: "round" });
drawLine(datapoints, 160, { color: "darkgreen", points: true });
```

#### Further investigation

By following D3 code, I found out that Chrome draws a point consisting in [the line caps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/lineCap) when

1. moving to some coordinates
2. closing the current subpath
3. moving again

By removing the second `moveTo` call, nothing shows up.

I'm not sure whether this behaviour should be considered a bug or not, because at high level we could see the sequence described above as a brush moved to a position and then moved again, never touching the canvas.

```js
ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
ctx.lineWidth = 2;
ctx.lineCap = "round";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(160, 20);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.moveTo(161, 20); // < this
ctx.stroke();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, stroking a zero-length line without closing a path, works for both `'square'` and `'round'` line caps in Firefox/Win. (`'butt'` caps are not rendered simply because they don't add any area to the final shape, so what is empty remains empty.)

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0 0 0 / 10%)';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

function strokeZeroLine (x, y, lineCap) {
  ctx.lineCap = lineCap;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x, y);
  ctx.stroke();
}

ctx.lineWidth = 10;
strokeZeroLine(40, 20, 'butt');
strokeZeroLine(40, 40, 'square');
strokeZeroLine(40, 60, 'round');
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="80" height="80"></canvas>
```